# Пропал апач с убунту

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Команда

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

не находит апач. Также не могу установить русский язык и мр3 плеер. Как я понял, вот в чем ошибкa

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> `Не удалось получить http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]`

404-я... подскажите? как поменять сервер закачки в убунту 9.1 и правильно ли я установил апач?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.10 давно в end-of-life.

Если очень надо именно 9.10 — поменяйте адреса в `/etc/apt/sources.list` с `*.archive.ubuntu.com` на `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Потом `apt-get update`.

Или, лучше, если не хотите практиковаться в некромантии, обновитесь на 12.04.